# Timeout a User Account?

Tags: windows-7, user-accounts

Is there a way to timeout a user account, as in after 15 minutes of inactivity lock the workstation or log the user out? This would need to be placed on a Windows 7 Home x64 system.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Another option is to use a scheduled task that will only start after the computer has been idle for 15 minutes:

[image]

The action can be something as simple as running a batch file that contains `shutdown -l` which will log off the user.

Comment: This is what I was looking for, thanks for the tip!

Answer (score 4):

If you only want to lock the account just configure a screen saver with a 15 minute time out and check the "On resume, display logon screen" box. The user will have to type in a password after 15 minutes of inactivity.