# force user logoff script for Windows 7

Tags: windows-7, user-accounts

Is there any way to force another user to logoff via command line in Windows 7 Home Premium?

My work VPN policy requires that there be only 1 user logged in, to log the other users off I have to run the command prompt as administrator, run the task manager and then right click and log them off. This is a little annoying. Ideally, I'd like an executable or batch script to run that did it all in one quick step. I've ran across a couple threads talking about logging users off after a set timeout, and that might work ok too (assuming there are any that work...my findings are that there aren't) - but I'd still like to know how to do it in one step if possible.

Is there any way to do what I am asking?

I'm not opposed to writing a .net app if I have to as well.

Answer (score 4):

You could automate the logoff command, using something like this batch file (adapted from [here](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/259436)):

```
@echo off
query session > c:\temp\session.txt
for /f "skip=2 tokens=2,3,4" %%i in (c:\temp\session.txt) DO if not "%%i"=="Geoff" logoff %%j
del c:\temp\session.txt
pause
```

This uses the [query session](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb490800.aspx) command to get a list of sessions, then the [for](http://www.microsoft.com/resources/documentation/windows/xp/all/proddocs/en-us/batch.mspx?mfr=true) command to parse the output, and finally the [logoff](http://www.microsoft.com/resources/documentation/windows/xp/all/proddocs/en-us/ts_cmd_logoff.mspx?mfr=true) command to log off other users.  You'll want to run the `query session` command to check the output on your machine.

On my machine, I get:

```
C:\Users\Geoff\Desktop>query session
 SESSIONNAME       USERNAME                 ID  STATE   TYPE        DEVICE
 services                                    0  Disc
>console           Geoff                     1  Active
```

the first two lines are garbage, so the `skip 2` part ignores those. The username, ID and State get put into the i, j, and k variables respectively.  You'll want to test it, and if it won't run as a non-administrator user then you can either right-click the file on your desktop and 'Run as Administrator', or you can create a shortcut to the batch file, then select Properties | Shortcut | Advanced | Run as Administrator.  Either way you'll get a UAC prompt.
Finally, if you want to run the batch file without the UAC prompt, you can go the more obscure task scheduler route: see [this post](http://www.sevenforums.com/tutorials/11949-elevated-program-shortcut-without-uac-prompt-create.html).

Comment: I don't think that will work for me. `logoff /?` yields nothing, further the MS page says this: "This article applies to a different version of Windows than the one you are using. Content in this article may not be relevant to you. Visit the Windows 7 Solution Center"

Comment: that's strange; possibly your edition of Windows doesn't include the command?  You could try the TSLOGOFF replacement utility on [this page](http://www.ctrl-alt-del.com.au/CAD_TSUtils.htm), it should (might??) do what you want.

Comment: A bit of reading turns up the fact that `logoff.exe` isn't available in Home Premium.  You can copy the it from `C:\Windows\System32` on a different Windows box, if you have one with a different license type, per [this answer](http://superuser.com/a/358546/60097).

Answer (score 2):

Check out [PSShutdown](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb897541) from MS.   You can use it with the `-o` option to log off the Console user, and make a batch file you could run with one click (or one right-click > run as administrator).

> PsShutdown is a command-line utility similar to the shutdown utility
>   from the Windows 2000 Resource Kit, but with the ability to do much
>   more. In addition to supporting the same options for shutting down or
>   rebooting the local or a remote computer, PsShutdown can logoff the
>   console user or lock the console (locking requires Windows 2000 or
>   higher).

Also, maybe check out this question: [Timeout a User Account?](https://superuser.com/questions/105033/timeout-a-user-account)

Comment: Funny, I ran across that and tried it but I must have done something wrong or misread it b\c it did not work. I'll mess with it again. +1 either way...I'll accept if I can get it to work.

Comment: I've tried several variations of this and can't get it to work :( I think it is only meant to logoff the *current* user, not another one

Comment: `psshutdown -f -o` should force off the user currently logged into the console, so that's weird. :)  All I can think of is to make sure you run the command window you're launching it from as an administrator.

Answer (score 1):

As an alternative to my [other answer](https://superuser.com/questions/350998/force-user-logoff-script-for-windows-7/351018#351018) (this question got me thinking!), you could also consider using a combination of two things:

1. Set up a scheduled task on each workstation to run a logoff script.  The trigger would be a specific event log entry.
2. Use a .vbs script on your own desktop to post the trigger entry to the event log.

Taking these in turn:

### Scheduled Task

You'd need to log in as each user, I think, and add a new task with a custom trigger: Triggers | New | 'On an event' | Custom | New Event Filter | XML | 'Edit manually'.  Then use something like the following for the XML:

```
<QueryList>
  <Query Id="0" Path="Application">
    <Select Path="Application">*[System[(Level=4 or Level=0) and (EventID=4)]] and *[EventData[Data[1]='EVERYBODY_OFF']]</Select>
  </Query>
</QueryList>
```

That will look for information events in the Application log with the EventID of 4 (information), and the data body of 'EVERYBODY_OFF'.  You can read more about event triggers [here](http://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/winservergen/thread/fac16f3c-d088-4d66-83d8-7139261dea83/).

The action should be able to be as simple as `shutdown -l`, which should trigger a logoff (you'll want to test it).

### Trigger Script

The following .vbs script will log the 'EVERYBODY_OFF' event on demand:

```
const EVENTLOG_INFORMATION = 4
strMessage = "EVERYBODY_OFF"
set objShell = CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
objShell.LogEvent EVENTLOG_INFORMATION, strMessage
```

### Stuff to Test

The bits I'm not sure of, and which will take a bit of testing:

- Is that the event message that is posted global to the machine? I.e., will all users see the task?
- Will the shutdown command run correctly in the context of the target user?

Answer (score 1):

Here's an interesting article from The Scripting Guys describing forced logoff triggered by event:

http://blogs.technet.com/b/heyscriptingguy/archive/2010/06/10/hey-scripting-guy-how-can-i-log-out-a-user-if-they-launch-a-particular-application.aspx

Suppose you can use logon or explorer.exe launch by user A as trigger event to log out user B.