# Is it possible to set a timeout for the logon screen in Windows 7?

Tags: windows-7, login, timeout

I have a device which I would like to not sit at the log on screen if nothing is entered. Ideally I would like to automatically log on as a kiosk user, but a restart would also work.

Is this even possible? I've googled and can only find lots of stuff about automatically logging off an account after a timeout...

Comment: Windows does not provide such a feature. you will have to try to find a third party solution, or roll your own.

Comment: Have you tried a scheduled task that starts after the computer has been idle for x minutes? The scheduled task could run `shutdown /r`. See [Timeout a User Account?](http://superuser.com/a/105037). Assumption: Displaying the Logon screen and doing nothing counts as idle time. If this works, please let me know and I will write up an answer.

Comment: I've tried setting an event to trigger when computer is idle for 1 minute, but nothing seems to happen. There is nothing in the task history either, so it seems like it doesn't run unless a user is logged in?

I did read somewhere that the idle state is only checked by the task scheduler once every 15 minutes, which is too long for me really.

Answer (score 0):

While this question is rather old and originally concerned Windows 7 it still has relevance on Windows 10.

So you need to automatically log in to a specific user, triggered by external means - be it a timer or a connected device, it doesn't matter for the purpose of this answer.

The textbook solution is to roll your own [credential provider](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/mt158211(v=vs.85).aspx) which calls upon [ICredentialProviderEvents::CredentialsChanged](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb776007(v=vs.85).aspx) when the device reports its ready state - or the timer elapses - and then adds in his own credential for the "kiosk user", marked as the default selection and autologin to facilitate automatically logging into the system.

As an added measure you can hide away the default credential providers using [ICredentialProviderFiler](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb776004(v=vs.85).aspx) to restrict logins even further.

Similar scenarios are alredy in use with logging in using biometric means or unlocking the system using a NFC or Bluetooth device.